# Text before <span> flag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my first BS coding experiment.
Website I'm scraping is [here](http://covers.com/Sports/NCAAF/Matchups?selectedDate=2015-10-13)
The issue I'm having is with this block of code:

```
<div class="cmg_team_name">
            ARST
            <span>101</span>
</div>
```

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "http://covers.com/Sports/NCAAF/Matchups?selectedDate=2015-10-13"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')
universities = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'cmg_team_name'})

#for university in universities:
#    print university.contents
#    print "****************"
print universities[0]
```

My question is how do I access only the text before the span flag.  In this example, I want just `ARST`.
I've tried `print universities[0].get_text()`, `print universities[0].string` yields `None` and also array notation.  I know how I would do it in C++, but I'm assuming python/BSoup would do this in one line...Thanks in adavance!

Comment: Please don't update your code to include the solution as it invalidates the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove span from div first and then clean extra characters like space and carriage returns.

```
for university in universities:
    span = [span.extract() for span in university('span')]
    univ = university.text.replace(' ','').replace('\r','').replace('\n','')
    print univ
```

Comment: That removes the span, thanks.  For some reason the `replace` statements aren't removing the whitespaces.  I'll use C++ to look at the ascii values to see what's going on.

Comment: I tested the code in my sytem. It works well. Can you show me the output you are getting after using the replace statements.

Comment: I added some sample output to the problem statement.  What's weird is that .strip() doesn't work either to clean up whitespaces.

Comment: That's because you writing university.text to output. I will update my code to give you a better idea.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I thought the `replace()` function was replacing in place and not returning a value.  Even when I read the documentation I just assumed that to be the case.  I need to read up on the underlying data structure for BeautifulSoup.